# WPF UI Control Background changing

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

The code below happens too fast to see the change.  Is there a way to slow this down without modifying the xaml style?  My only thought was to run a task but that seems a bit overdone.  Thoughts?

```
       switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Escape:
                ButtonStop.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#353535"));
                StopButton();
                ButtonStop.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
                break;
        }
```

This seems to work...  any caveats?

```
    private static async void PressBorder(Border control)
    {
        StopButton();
        var wait = Task.Delay(250);
        control.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#353535"));
        await wait;
        control.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
    }
```

Comment: `Task.Delay(...)` would be the preferred option. The calling eventhandler should be an async void.

Comment: Or run an animation.

Comment: Edited my OP, does that seem ok?

Comment: "does that seem ok?" - maybe, not possible to say. Show the code from the original event on down (abrreviated). You have now included StopButton() in the fire-and-forget. It better not throw exceptions.

Comment: good point... and it doesn't need to be in there.  I care more about the event than a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic pattern:

```
// avoid 'async void' almost everywhere else. Ok for an event handler
private async void HandleOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  try  // async void needs to do its own error handling 
  {    
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Escape:
                ButtonStop.Background = ...;

                // sandwich StopButton() in case it takes some time too   
                var waitTask = Task.Delay(250);  
                StopButton();
                await waitTask; 
                ButtonStop.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
                break;
        }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     // report it
  }

  // general cleanup & restore

}
```